# When querying for data, how to use rails for grouping to avoid duplicates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following query:

```
@items = AddressBook.select('email').where(:domain => 'hospital.com').
```

This returns back ~100 emails many which are duplicates. How can I get back only unique emails using rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this?

```
@items = AddressBook.select('DISTINCT email').where(:domain => 'hospital.com')
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid doing this on the database as I don't have an index for the email field and this would be pretty taxing?\

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a pretty standard SQL statement. I bet your database could handle it just fine. Try looking at the millisecond counts in the console both ways to see what kind of difference it makes on a fairly representative set of data.

Comment: @AnApprentice, I second Chris. The `where` condition narrows the result set significantly so DB SQL approach is better. As a rule of thumb, when I have to choose between SQL code and Ruby code, I always choose SQL code.

Answer (score 3):

```
  @items = AddressBook.select(:email).where(:domain => 'hospital.com').uniq
```

Same sql generated but different syntax